# XNA and Models not loading correctly, Or I am doing wrong

Tags: model, xna, fbx

I can successfully load a simple model (fbx) in XNA, but it shows that the "index was outside the bounds of the array" when I try to load my model of a spaceship. It has two meshes; one is the ship, the other is the cockpit. I have Mirror modifier on it to keep it symmetric and a subdivison modifier which makes it nice and smooth. The model was made in Blender.

It loads correctly when I remove the cockpit and the modifiers, but of course it is not good to look at in it's stripped form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the modifiers before export to make them permanent on the mesh.

Comment: Had actually no idea that it was possible. Thanks!